# Access VBA Filtering a combo box list based on Date field

Tags: sql, ms-access, combobox, vba

This is the line of code I am using to filter the EquipmentID1 combo box:

```
    EquipmentID1.RowSource = "SELECT tblEquipment.Equipment, tblEquipment.UnavailableFrom FROM tblEquipment WHERE tblEquipment.UnavailableFrom >= " & Me!EndDate & " OR tblEquipment.UnavailableFrom Is Null;"
```

UnavailableFrom is a date/time field in the tblEquipment table, and it can be empty. But the RowSource doesn't seem to work at all. However, it DOES work when I remove the part after the OR, but then it ignores Equipment with a blank UnavailableFrom field... help! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you just need to quote the date you're trying to use. Dates in Access SQL need to be quoted with the `#` character. Try this:

```
EquipmentID1.RowSource = _
  "SELECT tblEquipment.Equipment, tblEquipment.UnavailableFrom " & _
  "FROM tblEquipment " & _
  "WHERE tblEquipment.UnavailableFrom >= #" & Me!EndDate & "# " & _
    "OR tblEquipment.UnavailableFrom Is Null;"
```

Comment: Hmm, well I tried what you said and it worked. But I don't understand why

"SELECT tblEquipment.Equipment, tblEquipment.UnavailableFrom " & _
  "FROM tblEquipment " & _
  "WHERE tblEquipment.UnavailableFrom >= " & Me!EndDate & ";"

works without the #.

Comment: Not sure. Maybe without anything else following, Access is able to parse it and figure out that it's a date, but with the following text, it's trying to convert your date into part of the SQL syntax.

Comment: Without the `#` characters, the db engine would interpret 5/14/2015 as 5 divided by 14 divided by 2015 ... which is a really small number: 1.77242112725984E-04.  And in the context of that `WHERE` comparison, the db engine will treat that number as the Date/Time value Dec 30, 1899 12:00 AM.  So the query would return all rows whose *UnavailableFrom* values are >= Dec 30, 1899 12:00 AM.

Comment: Not exactly... It is >= 1899-12-30 00:00:15.314

Answer (score 2):

You also have to force a format of the date expression string if operating in a non-US environment:

```
EquipmentID1.RowSource = _
  "SELECT tblEquipment.Equipment, tblEquipment.UnavailableFrom " & _
  "FROM tblEquipment " & _
  "WHERE tblEquipment.UnavailableFrom >= #" & Format(Me!EndDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# " & _
    "OR tblEquipment.UnavailableFrom Is Null;"
```